# vertical middle aligned image and text side-by-side in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to print an image and text consecutively with two `div`s.

I have gained this output so far:

[image]     `sample text`

**But I need to display the text in the middle after the image, not at bottom.**

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="qr" style="display:inline-block; min-width:2.2cm; height:3.8cm; align: center;" >
        [ image_url  ]
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-width:3.8cm;">
        sample text
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width:21.1cm;
    height:29.8cm;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:0.4cm;
}
```

- the image is `qr code`. so i can't use `table` method
- the `div` using in `foreach` method. so cant change the dimension. how can i?

Comment: vertical-align:middle; doesn't works?

Comment: there is your answer below by Trix

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you after something like this:

```html
<div id="qr" style="display:inline-block; min-width:2.2cm; height:3.8cm; align: center;vertical-align: middle;" >
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Rl3.jpg" style="height:3.8cm;">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
  sample text
</div>
```

Comment: saved my days. thanks. but, is it possible to align the text place manually?

Comment: u r welcome. wat do u mean by manually? If you think this is not the exact desired output, please invest some time and edit your question to fulfill the desired output and let people edit or add new answers for that

Answer (score 4):

My way of doing this:

By using flex:

```html
<div class="one">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
    </div>
    <div>
        sample text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <div style="float:left"><img.. ></div>
> <div style="float:right">text</div>
> <div style="clear:both"/>
> ```

OR

> ```
> <div>
>     <img style="float: left; margin: ...;" ... />
>     <p style="float: right;">Text goes here...</p>
> </div>
> ```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438910/how-to-display-items-side-by-side-without-using-tables) or

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp)

Answer (score 3):

add following styles to text div

```
height:3.8cm;
line-height:3.8cm;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for my project, i have many images and dont like too many divs, and less code:

```
<div class="test">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"><span>sample text</span>
</div>

.test img {height:50px;width:auto;margin-bottom:-20px}
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/justzuhri/1dgfptan/)