# How to insert text next to image

Tags: html

I have attached an image, i want to display the full text next to image. But in the picture you can see that some text is below the image.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the HTML/CSS which you have tried so far?

Comment: use `div` to have 2 columns.

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/a401bvsk/1/

Comment: [Reference](https://www.uvm.edu/~bnelson/computer/html/wrappingtextaroundimages.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display items side-by-side without using tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438910/how-to-display-items-side-by-side-without-using-tables)

Comment: <h3><strong><a name="DEWA-ties-Chinese"></a>DEWA develops ties with Chinese Public &amp; Private sectors</strong></h3>
<p><img src="images/solar_panels_plant.jpg" border="0" alt="DEWA ties with Chinese" width="211" height="109" style="padding-right: 10px; float: left; border: 0;" /> Text, More text</p>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="image-grid"><img src=""/></div>
<div class="content-grid">Content Goes Here</div>

css 
.image-grid{float:left;width:40%;}
.content-grid{float:left;width:60%;}
```

it will work for you

Comment: <p><img src="images/solar_panels_plant.jpg" border="0" alt="DEWA ties with Chinese" width="211" height="109" style="padding-right: 10px; float: left; border: 0;"/>Text, More Text</p>

Comment: <style>
.image-grid{float:left;width:40%;}
.content-grid{float:left;width:60%;}
</style>
<p class="image-grid"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiypd.png" border="0" alt="DEWA ties with Chinese" width="211" height="109" style="padding-right: 10px;"/></p>
<p class="content-grid">Text, More Text</p>
Please go through the code throughly

Comment: The whole text went below the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class ="row">
  <div style="width: 50%; float:left">
     <img src ="/yourimagepath/image.jpg">
  </div>

  <div style="width: 50%; float:right">
     //Your content type here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ContaxPartners , Now the answer is updated. plz try once more

Comment: <h3><strong><a name="DEWA-ties-Chinese"></a>DEWA develops ties with Chinese Public &amp; Private sectors</strong></h3>
<p><img src="images/solar_panels_plant.jpg" border="0" alt="DEWA ties with Chinese" width="211" height="109" style="padding-right: 10px; float: left; border: 0;" /> Text, More text</p>